# Generate xml file from Laravel template

Tags: php, mysql, xml, laravel, laravel-4

I have a [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) template and I want to generate an XML file depending on it.

For example, the structure has a name, XPath and type. So the XML should look like this:

```
<name>
</name>
<type>
</type>
<xpath>
</xpath>
```

Of course I am looking for something more complex that can deal with relationships.

Is there any tool for that?

I am using MySQL, so maybe there is a tool for that, too? Or maybe a PHP script?

I already tried to search and all I have found is a tool to generate HTML forms from XSD and general XML from XSD.

#### Update

The tables and their columns are:

1. `xml_document` table with columns: `id`
2. `general_information` table with columns: `id`, `xml_document_id`, `domain`, `start_url` and `category
3. `master_information` table with columns: `id`, `xml_document_id`, `container`, and `next_page`
4. `master_attribute` table with columns: `id`, `master_information_id`, `name`, `xpath`, and `type`
5. `details_attribute` table with columns: `id`, `xml_document_id`, and `type`

As you may notice, the relationships between:

1. xml_document and master_information is one to one.
2. xml_document and general_information is one to one.
3. xml_document and details_attribute is one to many.
4. master_information and master_attribute is one to many

Comment: XML is very flexible, and as it stands you need more information in your question... can you explain the relationships in your app?  Can you give an example of what the resultant XML should look like?

Comment: @msturdy yes I can give you all the information you need. I need an xml file that represents my laravel model. the database table has many columns and I need to extract these columns but as xml document. did you got me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections), Collections and their relationships can be output to arrays:

```
$roles = User::find(1)->roles->toArray();
```

for example, I have two models, `User` and `Phone`, and a user `hasMany()` phones.

```
    users                  phones
    +----+--------+        +----+-----------+---------+
    | id | name   |        | id | number    | user_id |
    +----+--------+        +----+-----------+---------+
    |  1 | user 1 |        |  1 | 111111111 |       1 |
    |  2 | user 2 |        |  2 | 222222222 |       2 |
    +----+--------+        |  3 | 333333333 |       1 |
                           +----+-----------+---------+
```

we can return an array of this using the `toArray()` method, and `with()` to pull out all the related `Phones`:

```
$users = User::with('phones')->get()->toArray();
```

giving this *(I have `hidden` some of the fields on the model for the purposes of this answer)*:

```
  Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => user 1
            [phones] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 1
                            [number] => 111111111
                            [user_id] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => Array (
                            [id] => 3
                            [number] => 333333333
                            [user_id] => 1
                        )
                )    
        )    
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => user 2
            [phones] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 2
                            [number] => 222222222
                            [user_id] => 2
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

Then you can use any of the various methods for turning arrays into XML.  Here's one I've lifted from [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3289602/658210)

```
function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        is_array($v)
            ? array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k))
            : $xml->addChild($k, $v);
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

Example output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><0><id>1</id><name>user 1</name><phones><0><id>1</id><number>111111111</number><user_id>1</user_id></0><1><id>3</id><number>333333333</number><user_id>1</user_id></1></phones></0><1><id>2</id><name>user 2</name><phones><0><id>2</id><number>222222222</number><user_id>2</user_id></0></phones></1></root>
```

Comment: very nice answer, I will try it and update you. but after 1.30 hour. many thanks

Comment: when I tried this:`$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::find(4)->get()->toArray();` I got all the rows in the database not just the row `4`. then I tried this `$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::find(4)->toArray();` so I just get the columns not the relationships. I mean I just get the id(witch is only column in the table xmldocument). However, I should have got the other relationships. for exaple, I have one to many relationship with a table `master_information`, I didn't get these values. could you help please?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent - can you update your question with the relationships ?

Comment: Okay I will give you all the relationships, wait please to update the question

Comment: until now I have this code `$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', 'GeneralInformation', 'DetailsAttributes')->find(4)->toArray();` and it gives me all the information. I just still have to add the `MasterAttribute` to this question. I didn't know how. that is because the `MasterAttribute` is one to many with `MasterInformation` not with `XmlDocument` can you help please?

Comment: here we go `$xmlDocument = XmlDocument::with('MasterInformation', 'GeneralInformation', 'MasterInformation.MasterAttributes', 'DetailsAttributes')->find(4)->toArray();` it works, now I will check your code that transfer the array to xml.

Comment: That is enough for this question. I will accept your answer and then ask another answer about changing array to xml. will give you the link in case you would like to answer. appreicate your help

Comment: I created a new account because I couldn't ask more than 50 questions each 30 days and I asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556875/php-change-php-array-to-xml-format can you check pleaes?